# Addon - unable to add module in content_script for firefox addon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6, firefox-addon

Below is the project structure of a addon I'm trying to develop.

```
.
├── sc_back.js
├── sc_cont.js
├── icons
│   ├── addon
│   │   ├── icon-48.png
│   │   └── icon-96.png
│   └── context
│       ├── d-16.png
│       ├── d-32.png
│       ├── e-16.png
│       └── e-32.png
├── manifest.json
├── modules
│   └── sc_de.js
└── popup
    ├── action.css
    ├── action.html
    └── action.js
```

There is some JS code that is redundant between content script `sc_cont.js` and popup action script in `popup/action.js` so I decided to move that redundant part into a separate folder at `modules/sc_de.js`.

I added below lines at my content_script and at module script:

```
//sc_cont.js
import { xyz } from './modules/sc_de.js'

//modules/sc_de.js
export const xyz = {...}
```

I tried adding the modules script in `manifest.json` in the content_script array but it's not working. Haven't tried in web_accessible_resources as this is not supposed to be accessible from the DOM.

Problem is when I launch the addon debugger, it shows the following error:

`SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`
`SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

How do I resolve these errors to make the addon work? Also, do I need to do anything special in case of `popup/action.js` as well?

Comment: AFAIK modules aren't supported in content scripts. Probably because those are not like the extension pages with their own URL, but just a bunch of scripts "sideloaded" along web pages. Also, I'm not sure FF implemented module support for extensions pages yet. Chrome definitely did: https://crbug.com/769012

Comment: @wOxxOm how do I achieve this then? If there isn't a way to add modules, is there a workaround?

Comment: Hmm. You can use [scriptTagContext](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext) + requireJS.